# Python : How to set a variable to something such as "None" or "0" when there is no value from the request

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose you have something such as

```
a = b
```

but perhaps b does not exist.

can the value for a automatically be declared as "0" or.. perhaps "None" or something ?

Comment: i understand the "try" method but "try" method is probably less efficient than using an if b: statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on where `b` comes from, you could do

```
a = locals().get('b', 0)
```

or

```
a = globals().get('b', 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a try and except clause to catch the NameError of `b` not existing. See [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) in the Python docs.

```
try:
    a = b
except NameError:
    a = None
```

Comment: but that is too much coding.. i could have just done b = 0 with an if statement

Comment: @Margus why not? This is perfectly valid [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) syntax and is a common coding style within Python.

Comment: @Margus Don't Mindlessly Apply Cargo Cult Rules To Every Situation

Comment: @Ffisegydd Yes, unlike most compiled languages EAFP is perfectly viable in Python. Problem with try-catch is that you NEVER REMOVE them even if you should - in this case you should (You recommend permanent solution to temporary problem). My argument is that if he would use **pylint** or some IDE (Eclipse) that does static code analysis problem would never happen.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Note you can use static code checker that will find this bug. Examples:

- http://www.pylint.org/ (docs : http://docs.pylint.org/tutorial.html)
- Eclipse PyDev

### Solution 2

You can have **null-coalescing operator** in python with:

```
a = b if b is not None else "default value"
```

If your lazy then this can be simplified to

```
a = b or "some default value"
```

Example

```
42    or "something"    # returns 42
0     or "something"    # returns "something"
None  or "something"    # returns "something"
False or "something"    # returns "something"
""    or "something"    # returns "something"
```

Alternative way would be to check if variable exists in context:

```
if 'b' in locals():
  # local variable b exists.
if 'b' in globals():
  # local variable b exists.
```

For example this will result something like:

```
a = if 'b' in locals() b else 0
a = if 'b' in globals() b else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
a =vars().get('b', None)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this: Calling b, and if there's an error (if b not exist), then b=0.

```
try:
  b
except:
  b = 0
a = b
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.